# Capture payment on fulfilment in shopify

Tags: shopify

How do I make Shopify capture payment once an order is marked as fulfilled?

The only prefedined settings seems to be to capture instantly, or no auto capture at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your store to authorize a payment but not capture payment, Shopify will then present you with a capture payment button when you examine the order. So if you fulfill the order and you know you want to capture payment, press the button.

Comment: Yes, but the entire point is to do this automatic, once the order is fulfilled. So we don't have to manual work for every order

Comment: So write a simple script in Ruby, Python, Javascript, whatever, in the cloud and embed that script in an App that authenticates to your store. Hook that App up to your fulfillment house, and then you can automatically capture payments on fulfillment. Simple.

Comment: It just seems like such an obviously missing feature. Capture on fulfilment is afain used in most EU shops. 

Btw: Is the correct way write this app, not to add an app which listen to fulfilment events? 
We have multiple different 3 party apps which can all create fulfilments(Skybox for example) and I can't modify those. (We sell a mix of digital and physical products).

Comment: Listen for fulfillments as they are created/updated. Your App can then respond appropriately to capture funds. 

Your use pattern is not missing in Shopify as you comment. It is 100% possible and even dare I say easy to accomplish. It is not however obvious as most people do not work this way. There is a terrible amount of useless overhead when you fulfill things you have not collected any money for.